# SCIM schemas mapping to LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk, scim

I need to map SCIM core schema to LDAP to be used by UnboundId for operations in LDAP.

Is there a better approach to convert these schema??

e.g. In schema given [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hunt-scim-directory-00#section-2.2.3.4) I need to map:

`userName` to `uid`

`name.formatted` to `cn`

`name.familyName` to `sn (surname)`

...

So there are search filters that will be mapped:

```
`userName eq john` will be mapped to `(uid=john)`
```

One way is to write utility classes and map each SCIM attribute to LDAP attribute to convert SCIM filter to LDAP.

Is there any useful standard for doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Apache eSCIMo](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/escimo/trunk/) project, it uses XML based mapping file to map SCIM attributes to LDAP and vice versa. This is compliant with SCIM v2.0 schema, but some of the recent schema changes weren't added yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have several different ways of doing this, depending on the requirements.

- Create a simple `Enum` and map all values from either side
- Use a `Properties` file with keys like `schema.scim.userName = uid`
- Create an XML file with `<app-name>` and `<ldap-name>` elements

The last two options I usually parse into a `Map` object for easy access. 
The `Enum` option is fastest to set up but also offers least flexibility. The others can be externalized for customization.

Lately, I have only been using the XML variant because of the flexibility and easy mapping in both directions.